# Windows maintain explicit ACL of sub folder when copying

Tags: windows, permissions, network-shares, acl

We use a master project folder when creating new projects, one of the sub-folders has explicit access restrictions that are different to the containing folder.

That ACL is lost when you copy and paste the master folder into a new project. We don't want it to inherit any part of the ACL from the new project folder.

How do we maintain the Explicit ACL for that folder and it's sub-folders/files using file explorer. Is there a way to protect the explicit ACL across a copy paste.

Is there a way to do this via a script within the copied directory that would upon being double-clicked restore the ACL to the sub-directory?

I can run a powershell command to do it or an icacls command but can't see a way to do this via gui without getting all long winded about it.

Maybe I could just run a powershell script periodically, which searches for new folders under a particular directory and queries if there are any new ones matching the project folder and applying a set of ACL's to the subsequent new sub folders.

Comment: [`robocopy .\source\path .\destination\path /e /z /sec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) _(I'll create an answer later, but don't have the time at the moment)_

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for that, the problem we have is that the people doing this aren't really capable of using robocopy so unless it's a one off thing that I could do and then leave them with File Explorer afterwards it won't work.

Comment: Add the command to a text file and save it with a `.bat` extension, then all anyone has to do to copy the directory over is open/run the batch file. The other way to do this is to remove inherited permissions from the destination directory the pasted directory is going into _(may need some tinkering, so test first until the ACLs stick)_

Comment: In the sub folder I've created a backup icacls file for the folder and if I copy it over and run it from the command line that repairs the ACLs. I've then created a batch file in that folder that runs the same command and even running it as Administrator has no effect. I'm assuming the batch file isn't running it within that folder.

Comment: Please add the contents of the files within a codebox in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$SearchFolderPath = "C:\shares\Data\Clients & Projects\Projects"

$MasterFolder = "C:\shares\Data\ACL Scripts\Sample Folders\Master-test"

$AllFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchFolderPath -Directory -Recurse

$NameToMatch = "Folder Name to match"

$MasterAcl = Get-Acl -Path $MasterFolder

foreach($Folder in $AllFolders)
{   
    if($Folder.FullName -ne $MasterFolder -and $Folder.Name -match ".*$NameToMatch.*")
    {
       $MasterAcl | Set-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName  
       Write-Host "The Master ACL path has been set to $($Folder.FullName)" -ForegroundColor Green 
    }    
}
```

Comment: This could do with some explaination